# QuickLook an item stored in iCloud Drive

Tags: ios, icloud, quicklook

I made an app that stores a items (composed by a URL and a title) and then it can open the link associated with that item.
My problem is that I would like to access documents from iCloud Drive (the File app on iOS). 
In my app I have a share extension that grabs the url of the file (for example '/private/var/mobile/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/'). Now, when I try to preview the item in my app, through the QuickLook framework, I get this error:

```
[default] QLUbiquitousItemFetcher: <QLUbiquitousItemFetcher: 0x2831c4280> could not create sandbox wrapper. Error: Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=1 "couldn't issue sandbox extension com.apple.quicklook.readonly for '/private/var/mobile/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/file.txt': Operation not permitted"
```

How can I simply preview iCloud docs from my app?

Thanks a lot.